# Web page keeps loading indefinitely if removing (req, res, next) on passport.authenticate(...)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-jwt

I downloaded one sample project from internet. Below there are some fragments of the code:

On the `routes` file I have the following (just a fragment):

```
var authController = require('./controllers/authController'),
var passport = require('passport');
var authLoginFacebook =
    passport.authenticate(
        'facebook',
        {
            session: false,
            scope: ['public_profile', 'email']
        }
    );
var checkJwt = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate(
        'jwt',
        {session: false },
        function (err, user, info) {
            next();
        }
    )(req, res, next);
}

module.exports = function(app) {
    // ...
    app.get(
        '/api/auth/login/facebook/callback',
        checkJwt,
        authLoginFacebook,
        authController.login
    );
    // ...
}
```

On the `passport` file I have the following (just a fragment):

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var credentials = require('./credentials');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy({
                secretOrKey: credentials.secret,
                jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),
            },
            function(payload, done) {
                User.findById(
                    payload._id,
                    function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err, false);
                        }
                        if (user) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        )
    );

    var fbStrategy = credentials.facebook;
    fbStrategy.passReqToCallback = true;
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fbStrategy,
        function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            // asynchronous
            process.nextTick(function() {
                // check if the user is already logged in
                if (!req.user) {
                    User.findOne({
                        'facebook.id': profile.id
                    }, function(err, user) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        if (user) {
                            // if there is a user id already but no token (user was linked at one point and then removed)
                            if (!user.facebook.token) {
                                user.facebook.token = token;
                                user.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                                user.facebook.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();
                                user.save(function(err) {
                                    if (err)
                                        return done(err);
                                    return done(null, user);
                                });
                            }
                            return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
                        } else {
                            // if there is no user, create them
                            var newUser = new User();
                            newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
                            newUser.facebook.token = token;
                            newUser.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                            newUser.facebook.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();
                            newUser.save(function(err) {
                                if (err)
                                    return done(err);
                                return done(null, newUser);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // user already exists and is logged in, we have to link accounts
                    var user = req.user; // pull the user out of the session
                    user.facebook.id = profile.id;
                    user.facebook.token = token;
                    user.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                    user.facebook.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();
                    user.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    );

    // ...
};
```

I have few questions here:

1. why on: `passport.authenticate('jwt', ...` are passed these arguments: `(req, res, next)` and on `passport.authenticate('facebook', ...` don't while they are used in the same line one next to other?

   ```
   app.get(
       '/api/auth/login/facebook/callback',
       checkJwt,
       authLoginFacebook,
       authController.login
   );
   ```

   If I remove those arguments, then the web page keeps loading indefinitely.
2. why inside: `passport.use(new FacebookStrategy` is defined: `req.user`? where was declared the field: `user` for the object `req`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: this is a function invoking another function...which is required because of the callback using `next()`. The facebook function doesn't have that.

In other words, when you invoke `passport.authenticate`, the return value is actually going to be a function expecting the parameters `req, res, next`. Normally you don't need to wrap it, because it just works. However, in this case there is a callback function being passed in as an argument, and that callback function needs access to the `next` parameter. So you have to wrap the whole thing to gain access to that `next` parameter.

*Note: the wrapped function isn't actually returning anything to/through the wrapping function. `passport.authenticate()` returns a function, and then this return function is self-invoked with the parameter group that follows. But this second self-invoked function result isn't captured as a variable or returned or anything.

The reason is that the important thing is either sending a response using the `res` parameter *or* allowing express to continue to the next layer of middleware/etc by calling the `next()` callback parameter. It's all happening asynchronously, and flow is directed using the callbacks.

```
var checkJwt = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate(
        'jwt',
        {session: false },
        function (err, user, info) {
            next();
        }
    )(req, res, next);
}
```

the req.user would be a user from a previous login, which i believe passport.js normally stores using the `express-session` package.

Comment: you said: `the return value is actually going to be a function expecting the parameters req, res, next`, but the function: `checkJwt` is not returning any value because is not using the keyword: `return`. I think there is something I don't understand here?

Comment: You're right, I used the incorrect term when I said "returning." The whole chain of middleware etc in express is functioning asynchronously. It doesn't matter so much what is returned. When a layer of middleware is finished and wants to allow the process to continue on to the next layer, it calls the `next()` callback. And if it "rejects" (as one would say in Promise terms), it would call the `res.end()` or something like that.